No puedo deserializar el objeto JSON al hacer un cliente API REST
Actualmente estamos creando un cliente para consumir un API REST. En un principio, el cliente funcionaba correctamente, pero luego de consultar el API REST en fechas diferentes, comenzamos a notar un error en tiempo de compilación que detiene la descarga de datos. Procedemos a presentar lo que hemos hecho:
En primer lugar, presentamos parte del JSON que hemos descargado para que puedan validar los tipos de datos que estamos recibiendo:
[
  {
    "uniqueID": 1098828384,
    "plate": "BU-27",
    "GPSDate": "2024-09-10T06:02:57.000Z",
    "latitude": 0.95452,
    "longitude": -76.59358,
    "speed": 0,
    "course": 335,
    "odometer": 29657.417,
    "receivedDate": "2024-09-10T06:03:01.000Z",
    "stateInfo": {
      "stateData": {
        "stateParam": "11+",
        "stateDetail": "Parado"
      }
    },
    "GPSQuality": 1,
    "CANInfo": {
      "CANData": []
    },
    "peripheralsInfo": {
      "peripheralsData": [
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Motor",
          "peripheralsValue": "Parado"
        },
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Bateria",
          "peripheralsValue": "Cargando"
        },
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Pedal panico",
          "peripheralsValue": "off"
        },
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Inmovilizador",
          "peripheralsValue": "Bloqueado"
        }
      ]
    },
    "geofenceInfo": {
      "geofenceData": {
        "geofencePoint": "PUNTO 161",
        "geofencePolygon": "UF5-6-7 VAR SANFRANCISCO"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "uniqueID": 1098828555,
    "plate": "VD-283",
    "GPSDate": "2024-09-10T06:04:35.000Z",
    "latitude": 1.02244,
    "longitude": -76.62556,
    "speed": 0,
    "course": 139,
    "odometer": 14171.451,
    "receivedDate": "2024-09-10T06:04:37.000Z",
    "stateInfo": {
      "stateData": {
        "stateParam": "11+",
        "stateDetail": "Parado"
      }
    },
    "GPSQuality": 1,
    "CANInfo": {
      "CANData": [
        {
          "CANParam": "fuelLevel1",
          "CANValue": "79.2"
        },
        {
          "CANParam": "RPM",
          "CANValue": "599"
        },
        {
          "CANParam": "speed",
          "CANValue": "0"
        },
        {
          "CANParam": "coolantTemperature",
          "CANValue": "57"
        }
      ]
    },
    "peripheralsInfo": {
      "peripheralsData": [
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Motor",
          "peripheralsValue": "En marcha"
        },
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Bateria",
          "peripheralsValue": "Cargando"
        },
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Pedal panico",
          "peripheralsValue": "off"
        },
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Inmovilizador",
          "peripheralsValue": "Bloqueado"
        }
      ]
    },
    "geofenceInfo": {
      "geofenceData": {
        "geofencePoint": "PUNTO 161",
        "geofencePolygon": "UF5-6-7 VAR SANFRANCISCO"
      }
    }
  }
]

Estas son las clases que creamos para recibir el JSON:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FlotasNetDAL
{
    public class CANData
    {
        public string? CANParam { get; set; }
        public string? CANValue { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace FlotasNetDAL
{
    public class geofenceData
    {
        public string? geofencePoint { get; set; }
        public string? geofencePolygon { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace FlotasNetDAL
{
    public class peripheralsData
    {
        public string? peripheralsParam { get; set; }
        public string? peripheralsValue { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace FlotasNetDAL
{
    public class stateData
    {
        public string? stateParam { get; set; }
        public string? stateDetail { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace FlotasNetDAL
{
    public class vehicleInfo
    {
        public long uniqueID { get; set; }
        public string? plate { get; set; }
        public DateTime GPSDate { get; set; }
        public float latitude { get; set; }
        public float longitude { get; set; }
        public int speed { get; set; }
        public int course { get; set; }
        public float odometer { get; set; }
        public DateTime receivedDate { get; set; }
        public stateData[]? stateInfo { get; set; }
        public int GPSQuality { get; set; }
        public CANData[]? CANInfo { get; set; }
        public peripheralsData[]? peripheralsInfo { get; set; }
        public geofenceData? geofenceInfo { get; set; }
    }
}

Este es el metodo que estamos desarrollando para consumir el API REST:
using FlotasNetDAL;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace FlotasNetBLL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 2024-08-28: Se crean las variables sencibles.
    /// </summary>
    public class FlotasNetClient
    {
        // 2024-08-29: Creacion de las variables a obtener del appsettings.json
        private static string? _baseUrl;
        private static string? _username;
        private static string? _sha256Concatenado;
        private static string? _company;


        /// <summary>
        /// 2024-08-29: Constructor de la clase.
        /// </summary>
        public FlotasNetClient()
        {
            // 2024-08-29: Con esta variable tengo el acceso al appsettings.json para tomar informacion de alli.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

            _baseUrl = builder.GetSection("baseUrl").Value;
            _username = builder.GetSection("username").Value;
            _sha256Concatenado = builder.GetSection("sha256Concatenado").Value;
            _company = builder.GetSection("company").Value;
        }


        // 2024-09-04 13:40: Este es otra forma de hacer le metodo anterior, busancdo simplificar. 
        //public async Task<IEnumerable<vehicleInfo>> GetVehicleInfoByDate(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
        public async Task<vehicleInfo[]> GetVehicleInfoByDate()
        {
            //string StartDateISO8601 = StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz");
            //string EndDateISO8601 = StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz");
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://servicios.flotasnet.es:1443/api/GetInfoVehicleByDate2?startdate=2024-10-09T01%3A00%3A00Z&enddate=2024-10-09T01%3A05%3A00Z"),
                //RequestUri = new Uri($"{_baseUrl}/GetInfoVehicleByDate2?startdate={StartDateISO8601:O}&enddate={EndDateISO8601:O}"),
            Headers =
                {
                    { "user-agent", "vscode-restclient" },
                    { "accept", "application/json" },
                    { "user", _username },
                    { "password", _sha256Concatenado },
                    { "company", _company },
                },
            };
            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                // 2024-09-13 11:19: Con esta linea se genera la pagina con los datos.
                var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                // 2024-09-11 08:19: Con esta linea, vemos los datos en consola para hacer busquedas y ver lo que 
                // estamos recibiendo.
                Console.WriteLine(body);
                // 2024-09-13 11:19: Con esta linea se convierte la pagina llena de datos en una coleccion en C#.
                var Des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<vehicleInfo[]>(body);
                return Des;
            }
        }
    }
}

Y este es el archvo program.cs con el cual ejecutamos en consola:
using FlotasNetBLL;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var client = new FlotasNetClient();
var vehicleData = await client.GetVehicleInfoByDate();

En el momento en que compilamos el código, este comienza a funcionar correctamente y podemos ver en consola la descarga de los datos, hasta que llega un momento en que esta descarga se detiene y nos genera el siguiente error:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FlotasNetDAL.CANDataObj]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path '[0].CANInfo.CANData', line 1, position 310.'

En primer lugar notamos que las fallas se estan presentando con la siguente propiedad en la clase vehicleInfo: public CANData[]? CANInfo { get; set; }
Esta propiedad es relevante en nuestro desarrollo, ya que los datos de mayor importancia se obtienen allí.
Lo primero que hicimos para tratar de corregir la novedad fue cambiar de esto:
public CANData[]? CANInfo { get; set; }

a esto:
public CANData? CANInfo { get; set; }

Esto lo hicimos porque pensábamos que realmente se estaba comportando como un objeto y no como un array. Luego de compilar el código con esta modificación, comenzamos a recibir datos, lo que nos hizo suponer que esa era la falla y que ahora ya estaba corregida, pero después de un rato, nuevamente se presentó un error de compilación y se detuvo la descarga de datos. El error que obtivmos fue el siguiente:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FlotasNetDAL.CANDataObj]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path '[0].CANInfo.CANData', line 1, position 310.'

Al comparar los 2 errores que se han presentando, notamos que son exactamente el mismo error.
Otra cosas que hicimos fue convertir los parámetros que estaban definidos como arreglos en listas pasando de esto:
public CANData[]? CANInfo { get; set; }

A esto:
public List<CANData>? CANInfo { get; set; }

Los resultados fueron similares y continúa generendose el mismo error.
En estos momentos no vemos qué más hacer, ya que consideramos que las clases fueron realizadas conforme al JSON que se está recibiendo, pero a pesar de ello, hay algo que no logramos identificar para que funcione correctamente.

Según el JSON la propiedad CANinfo es un objeto que contiene la propiedad CANdata que es un array de objetos y cada uno de esos objetos contienen las propiedades CANParam y CANValue por lo que tus clases debiesen ser así:
EDIT:
Ninguna de las propiedades de tu objeto raiz vahicleInfo es un array, todas las que tienes como array están mal, puedes cambiarlas de la siguiente forma
namespace FlotasNetDAL
{
    public class vehicleInfo
    {
        public long uniqueID { get; set; }
        public string? plate { get; set; }
        public DateTime GPSDate { get; set; }
        public float latitude { get; set; }
        public float longitude { get; set; }
        public int speed { get; set; }
        public int course { get; set; }
        public float odometer { get; set; }
        public DateTime receivedDate { get; set; }
        public StateInfo? stateInfo { get; set; } // aquí el cambio
        public int GPSQuality { get; set; }
        public CANInfo? CANInfo { get; set; } // aquí el cambio
        public PeripheralsInfo? peripheralsInfo { get; set; }  // aquí el cambio
        public geofenceData? geofenceInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class PeripheralsData
    {
        public string peripheralsParam { get; set; }
        public string peripheralsValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class PeripheralsInfo
    {
        public PeripheralsData[] peripheralsData { get; set; }
    }

    public class StateData
    {
        public string stateParam { get; set; }
        public string stateDetail { get; set; }
    }

    public class StateInfo
    {
        public StateData stateData { get; set; }
    }

    public class CANInfo {
        public class CANData[] CANData { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class CANData
    {
        public string? CANParam { get; set; }
        public string? CANValue { get; set; }
    } 
}

PD: te dejo un link a una herramienta que convierte un JSON en objecto c#
https://json2csharp.com/
pegas todo el json y te crea las clases, es muy buena, este es un ejemplo pegando tu JSON:
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(myJsonResponse);
public class CANDatum
{
public string CANParam { get; set; }
public string CANValue { get; set; }
}
public class CANInfo
{
    public List<CANDatum> CANData { get; set; }
}

public class GeofenceData
{
    public string geofencePoint { get; set; }
    public string geofencePolygon { get; set; }
}

public class GeofenceInfo
{
    public GeofenceData geofenceData { get; set; }
}

public class PeripheralsDatum
{
    public string peripheralsParam { get; set; }
    public string peripheralsValue { get; set; }
}

public class PeripheralsInfo
{
    public List<PeripheralsDatum> peripheralsData { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public int uniqueID { get; set; }
    public string plate { get; set; }
    public DateTime GPSDate { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public int speed { get; set; }
    public int course { get; set; }
    public double odometer { get; set; }
    public DateTime receivedDate { get; set; }
    public StateInfo stateInfo { get; set; }
    public int GPSQuality { get; set; }
    public CANInfo CANInfo { get; set; }
    public PeripheralsInfo peripheralsInfo { get; set; }
    public GeofenceInfo geofenceInfo { get; set; }
}

public class StateData
{
    public string stateParam { get; set; }
    public string stateDetail { get; set; }
}

public class StateInfo
{
    public StateData stateData { get; set; }
}


LPZadkiel, muchas gracias por la información. En primer lugar hicimos las recomendaciones que nos indicas y sucedio exactamente igual que las veces anteriores., se comenzo a ejecutar el codigo y luego salto el mismo error. Pensamos que continuabamos haciendo las cosas de alguna forma mal, asi que utlizamos el programa que nos recomiendas para crear la clase desde cero y luego de hacer los ajustes, nuevamente compilamos el codigo y salto el mismo error.

acabo de notar que tienes un problema en todas las propiedades que tienes como array, todas son objetos en el JSON y estos contienen una propiedad que es array, en tu objeto vehicleInfo ninguna de sus propiedades debiese ser un array

si copias y pegas tal cual lo que te entrega la herramienta y cambias Root por vehicleInfo debiese funcionar sin problemas

Asi es LPZadkiel, buscando evitar error copie y pegue y deserilize asi: var myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(body); pero apesar de ello, se ejucuta el codigo se descargan datos y luego sale el error, pareciera como si fuera algun tipo de dato que hiciera eso, pense que era depronto los null pero los parametros los permiten ya que les pusimos el simbolo ? para que asi sea. Aun no logramos encontrar el problema.

el mensaje de error tiene que ver con los array, si el mensaje de error cambió puede ser otra cosa

Algo que vemos anormal en el error que se genera es lo siguiente: El error especifica que la falla esta relacionado con la clase 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FlotasNetDAL.CANDataObj] pero lo raro es que no tenemos ninguna clase con el nombre CANDataObj en nuestro nace space. En el momento no sabemos como acceder a esa clase que esta indicando el error porque no existe.

las variables nullable me generan problemas, prueba quitandole lo nullable a todas las variables mira el ejemplo que hice con tu información https://dotnetfiddle.net/DOgQet
